# Flask Bad Request 400

Tags: json, flask, pycharm

I was using the Flask framework I tried the basic code to see if it was going to work, I saw it from a YouTuber named DeepLizard, and their code seemed for work fine, but when I ran it on Pycharm, it constantly gives me a 
"Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" 
Error message it is very frustrating here is the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request


app = Flask(__name__) #creates an instance of flask app. And the name 
of application module.
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/hello', methods = ["POST", 'GET'])
def hello1():
message = request.get_json(force =True)
name = message['name']
response = {
    'greeting': 'hello, ' + name + '!'
}

return jsonify(response)
```

I tried to use both methods = ['POST'] and also ['POST', 'GET'], neither have worked. I've searched everywhere and cannot seem to find the answer any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[This is the html code we are trying to use for the backend.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc1JN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using `get_json` is not flexible and in my experience it raises too many errors, without having your request content I can't judge, but here's a better way to do it :

**Get the request data as a dictionary :**

To do that use either `request.args` if you're using a GET request, or `request.form` if you're using a POST request . Now you can treat those as normal dictionaries (even though they're `Immutable Multi Dict` but you can manipulate them like any python dictionary except assigning new values .

**Get the data as JSON :**

I think using the `json` module is more powerful, just use `json.dumps` function and pass any dict to convert it into JSON, to get a dict from JSON string use : `json.loads`

**Meaning of your error**

You're recieving a bad request which means that you're sending some wrong data or requesting the route in a wrong way, by default your route accepts only GET requests .

Comment: I didn't add a front end yet, I was just testing to see if it would work, I'll try some of the suggestions.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc1JN.png here is a picture of what I am trying to do with the html in flask, I rendered the template it works correctly, but I am not sure how to approach this now.